# Goes to Next page but it does not scrape its elements using Selenium and Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all pages using Selenium and clicking Next page button. However, URL does not change as I move to the next page. I am able to move to all pages, but I only get items scraped from the first page and not sure how to make it work for everything.
Any suggestions on what I should do?

Thank you in advance!

The code:

```
class MilieuProperties(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'milieu_properties'
    start_urls = [
        # FOR SALE
        'https://www.milieuproperties.com/search-results.aspx?paramb=ADVANCE%20SEARCH:%20Province%20(Western%20Cape),%20%20Area%20(Cape%20Town)',
        'https://www.milieuproperties.com/RentalByCategory.aspx'
    ]

    def __init__(self):


        
        #headless options
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('path',options=options)

    
    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        current_page_number = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text
        while True:
            try: 
                elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]/a[text()="Next" and not(@class)]')))
                elem.click()
            except TimeoutException:
                break
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text != current_page_number)
            current_page_number = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text


        offering = response.css('span#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblbreadcum::text').get()
        try:
            offering = 'rent' if 'Rental' in offering else 'buy'
        except TypeError:
            offering = 'buy'

        base_link = response.request.url.split('/')
        try:
            base_link = base_link[0] + '//' + base_link[2] + '/'
        except:
            pass

        for p in response.xpath('//div[@class="ct-itemProducts ct-u-marginBottom30 ct-hover"]'):
            link = base_link + p.css('a::attr(href)').get()

            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                callback=self.parse_property,
                meta={'item': {
                    'url': link,
                    'offering': offering,
                    }},
            )


    def parse_property(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
        . . .
```

Comment: The easiest solution is just NOT to use Scrapy along with Selenium. You can scrape all the data you want with Selenium only

Comment: @JaSON I would only make the Scrapy request for the property pages and do not quite understand why this would not work

Comment: If you click Next button in Selenium and URL doesn't change you won't get required data by requesting the same page HTML with Scrapy, you need to pass Cookies from Selenium to Scrapy. But this seem to be redundant action since you're already on required page and you can get data with selenium code directly. Simply put, there is no synchronization between Scrapy and Selenium, so when you moved to next page with Selenium Scrapy doesn't "know" about it

Comment: @JaSON I am not sure then how can I take all the links to property pages and continue gathering data from those?

Comment: You don't need any links and HTTP-requests. Just click Next button to load new HTML DOM and scrape required data with Selenium built-in methods/properties

Comment: @JaSON I would like to actually scrape information from the properties themselves, not just the search page, for example, `https://www.milieuproperties.com/To-Rent/commercial---office/western-cape/durbanville/durbanville-central/515627`
and to get to it I need to go to that page, which Scrapy was doing. Now I'm unsure how to get info from these pages, not just the whole search page. I don't know if I'm being clear..?

Comment: So you want to open [this page](https://www.milieuproperties.com/search-results.aspx?paramb=ADVANCE%20SEARCH:%20Province%20(Western%20Cape),%20%20Area%20(Cape%20Town)) extract links of all search results, switch to next page, extract all results... etc?

Comment: @JaSON yes! exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data without using Scrapy. Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

links = []
url = 'https://www.milieuproperties.com/search-results.aspx?paramb=ADVANCE%20SEARCH:%20Province%20(Western%20Cape),%20%20Area%20(Cape%20Town)'
driver.get(url)
current_page_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text
while True:
    links.extend([link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.hoverdetail a')])
    try: 
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1"]/a[text()="Next" and not(@class)]')))
        elem.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text != current_page_number)
    current_page_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lvDataPager1>span').text

print(links)
```

Comment: thank you very much for this! Is there a way, once I have these links, to visit those links and scrape them? That was why I used scrapy before @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg you can just iterate over list of links and open each one by one `for link in links: driver.get(link)`.